# Mongo $nin query with case insensitivity

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, boolean

I'm using this  `$nin` query for case  insensitivity. but not work

```
first_name: { $nin: [ "/^rahul/i", "/^Bhosale/i" ] }
```

with this query execution I was unable to found case insensitive.

So please suggest me with appropriate Query for case insensitive in `$nin`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotation, become

```
first_name: { $nin: [ /^rahul/i, /^Bhosale/i ] }
```